# Dynamically bind grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am not able to view rows in my grid which I am binding to it dynamically here is my code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DisplayGrid();
    }

    private void DisplayGrid()
    {
        var records = new ObservableCollection<Record>();
        records.Add(new Record(new Property("FirstName", "ABC"), new Property("LastName", "DEF")));
        records.Add(new Record(new Property("FirstName", "GHI"), new Property("LastName", "JKL")));

        var columns = records.First()
            .Properties
            .Select((x, i) => new { Name = x.Name, Index = i })
            .ToArray();

        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            var binding = new Binding(string.Format("Properties[{0}].Value", column.Index));
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = column.Name, Binding = binding });
        }
    }
}

class Record
{

    readonly ObservableCollection<Property> _properties = new ObservableCollection<Property>();

    public Record(params Property[] properties)
    {
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            _properties.Add(property);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Property> Properties
    {
        get { return _properties; }
    }


}
```

and in my XAML

```
       <DataGrid
        Name="dataGrid"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Records}"/>
```

I am only able to display headers in my grid but not the rows..

Thanks

Comment: Post your Record class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an  observable collection Records as a public property to your MainWindow:

```
public ObservableCollection<Record> Records {get; set;}
```

and use it instead of the private variable `records`. Also add `DataContext = this;` to the constructor.